# Can you kill your allied Faction after completing the story?

Tags: fallout-4

I allied with BOS throughout the whole play through, have finished the game, and the Institute and Railroad are gone. However I'd also like to kill the BOS, if possible. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you try shooting them?

Comment: There is no quest for it if you mean that. Once you "ended" the game with a faction its done, they are then the faction that survived. Only possible thing you can do is be your own BOSS and kill them all, but you will never be able to shoot the aircraft down.

Answer (score 2):

[@GEnGEr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246827/can-you-kill-your-sided-faction-after-completing-the-story/#comment341204_246827) My thoughts, exactly.

There are **no actual quests to destroy the last surviving faction**, but you can have so much fun mass murdering them at your own risk. Just make sure you save the game before you start the ultimate destruction.

Comment: I think this is basically true. Would be better to determine if there are still any essential characters for the main faction after the main quest is completed.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended overkill storyline, in short:

(Based on info from the Fallout wiki and other forums, YouTube: Oxhorn, TheEpicNate315, The Efficient Gamer, and my gameplay on PS4)

1. Side with the Minutemen and eliminate BOS, Institute, and Railroad (the order is on you; only don't assemble Liberty).
2. Exile Preston and Ronnie to some hole in Far Harbor (which has been cleaned of all factions before) due to their essential stats.
3. Become Overboss, side with the Raiders, and conquer the whole Commonwealth. Enemy with Minutemen, which exist only on Harbor.
4. Return to Nuka-World and slay all the Raiders here and in the Commonwealth. I'm not sure if Gage will become non-essential; if not, exile him before.

Comment: By "Cage", you mean "Gage", right? (I've edited your answer to say "Gage", however, if am incorrect, please clarify who "Cage" is.)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I mean Gage..

Answer (score -1):

If you want to destroy the BOS when you're with them talk to Preston Garvey about the brotherhood and you will get a quest where you will destroy the airship. I did this but Liberty Prime is still alive.